# Can we simplify this proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I'm reading [Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra](http://uap.unnes.ac.id/ebook/mathematics%20ebook/Algebra/Linear%20Algebra,%202nd%20ed%20-%20Kenneth%20Hoffman,%20Ray%20Kunze,%201971.pdf) and on page 313 they prove the following theorem:

> **Theorem 16** On a finite-dimensional inner product space of positive dimension, every self-adjoint operator has a (non-zero) characteristic
>   vector.

They proved this in the following way:

[image]

I didn't understand:

1. where do they use the fact $A=A^*$
2. Why does $c$ be a real scalar matters?

**To sum up:**  Why don't they simply say the characteristic polynomial, $\det(xI-A)$, is a polynomial of degree $n$ over the complex numbers then there is $c$ such that $\det (cI-A)=0$ and then there is a non-zero $X$ such that $AX=cX$ which follows there is a non-zero vector $\alpha\in V$ such that $T\alpha=c\alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

Q: Where do they use the fact that $A=A^{*}$

Author says  "$U(X)=AX$ defines a self adjoint linear operator $U$ on $W$". To show that $U$ is self adjoint, you will need the fact that $A$ is self adjoint.

Hint: $$\langle U(X)\mid Y\rangle \;= \langle AX\mid Y\rangle\;=Y^{*}AX\;=(A^{*}Y)^{*}X^{*}\;=\;\langle X\mid A^{*}Y\rangle$$

And for the second question. We are using the fact that All  eigenvalues  of  a  self-adjoint  operator are real . That's why real scalar matters.  The self ad-jointness of $U$ forces $c$ to be real.

Read the comments on page 313 just below the proof.
It says "The argument shows that characteristic polynomial of a self adjoint matrix  has real coefficients, in spite of the fact that the matrix may not have real entries."

Comment: Do you mean: $Y^{*}AX\;=(A^{*}Y)^{*}X$?

Comment: I understood the answer for the first question, but I'm still struggling to follow the answer to the second one. I know why all eigenvalues of $U$ are real, what I don't understand is where we are using this fact to prove the statement of the theorem. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I think I know, is it because the case where $V$ is real?

Comment: Right. First, the fact that c is real is proven (theorem 15), not assumed. As to why you want to prove it in the first place - it allows to that even in a real space there will be a solution to the the characteristic equation. It's interesting that in general we can only be sure that a polynomial has a complex root, but after we know that we can prove it's actually real because A is Hermitian (self-adjoint).